# Highlighting a website section using .html#link

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to use CSS to highlight the section that has been linked to?

If not can I get the #link in JavaScript some how?
IE

```
var section = $(window).link();
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: When the link is clicked it also goes just bellow the section that I am linking to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `:target` CSS pseudo-class:

```css
:target {
  background-color: #F4D03F;
}
```

```html
<a href="#link">Click me</a>
<h2 id="link">Highlight me</h2>
```

---

Also, to fade it in (like on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32158458/highlighting-a-website-section-using-htmllink/32158466#32158466) (reload the page)) add a `transition`:

```
:target {
    background-color: #F4D03F;
    transition: 0.8s;
}
```

```css
:target {
  background-color: #F4D03F;
    transition: 0.8s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#link">Click me</a>
<h2 id="link">Highlight me</h2>
```

*(I will happily demonstrate how to fade the highlight it in and then out again, like on StackOverflow, if you ask it as a seperate question :)*